# How can i highlight n sequence string words

Tags: javascript, html, regex

This my script to Highlight a specific word from text string my only problem is when I want to highlight three sequence words it just the 1st word highlighted then 2nd still without highlight then the third one it is highlighted

The `*` its a truncation and works well

- This an Example to highlight `n` sequence words:

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "This reference is to serve test as a useful reference for testing whether the styling of reference works or not. Adtest all occurrences of 'reference' should be given a color of red tests" 
};

//here i need to highlighte "reference" "is" "to" "serve" "test*" (n sequnence words)

var wordsToHighlight = 'reference is to serve test*';
var result = row["Abstract"];

wordsToHighlight.split(" ").forEach(function (word) {
  word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*');
  result = result.replace(new RegExp('((?:\\s|^)' + word + '(?:\\s|$))', "g"),'<span style="color: red;">$1</span>');
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

My object is to highlights all the words in the paragraph

looking for your suggestion.

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired output, I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: @DBS you can my example by clicking on RUN code snippet its contain an example

Comment: @DBS I want to highlight all the words as an example  'reference is to serve test*' in the paragraph. (*) it's a truncation

Comment: Try [`result.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "g"),'$1<span style="color: red;">$2</span>')`](https://jsfiddle.net/9a68oyh4/2/)

Comment: thanks! but you need to add the third argument **result =  result.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(\\s|$)', "gi"),'$1<span style="color: red;">$2</span>$3');**

Comment: @MokiNex You have not checked my solution. There are only 2 groups, you cannot use `$3`, it will be inserted as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the last whitespace matching group pattern into a non-consuming pattern, a positive lookahead:

```
result = result.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "g"),'$1<span style="color: red;">$2</span>');
```

For example, the pattern with a `test` word will look like `/(\s|^)(test)(?=\s|$)/` and will allow `(\s|^)` to match the whitespace that was tested with `(?=\s|$)` during the previous match.

There will only be 2 capturing groups, so the replacement should be `'$1<span style="color: red;">$2</span>'`: the first `$1` will insert the leading whitespace (if captured) and the `$2` will insert the word matched.

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a68oyh4/2/):

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "This reference is to serve test as a useful reference for testing whether the styling of reference works or not. Adtest all occurrences of 'reference' should be given a color of red tests" 
};

//here i need to highlighte "reference" "is" "to" "serve" "test*" (n sequnence words)

var wordsToHighlight = 'reference is to serve test*';
var result = row["Abstract"];

wordsToHighlight.split(" ").forEach(function (word) {
  word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*');
  result = result.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "g"),'$1<span style="color: red;">$2</span>');
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: do you have an idea how to do interrogation point also as a truncation feature **?= one character (e.g. nurse? --> nurses, nursed, ...)** or  **(for two characters e.g. te??-->test, teen)**

Comment: @MokiNex You need to replace `?` with `.`: `word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*').replace(/\?/g, '.');`. However, you should think of a way to allow users to enter a literal `?` and `*` symbols.

Comment: there only one issue in this expression one i have a row contain whitespace for example ("    reference     is       to serve test" ) in this example it will highlight reference and before the word reference it will add me this me phrase style="color: red;">style="color: red;">  could help me to fix that thank you

Comment: I mean if I have 2 whitespaces or more before and after the word that I want to highlight it will be a problem and appear to me that problem

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it's only highlighting every second word lies in the regex and the replacement string. Your regex matches every occurrence preceded and followed by a whitespace.

So `<whitespace>word<whitespace>` gets replaced with `<span style="color: red;">word</span>`, which works fine.

Now say we have `<whitespace>word<whitespace>word<whitespace>`. After the first run we have `<span style="color: red;">word</span>word`. As there is no whitespace before the second `word`, the regex can't match it.

A simple solution would be to surround your replacement string with whitespaces, but that still leaves us with `'reference'` failing, but that is due to the regex itself.